# Doctrine2 Entity relationship with Where Condition

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

My database schema;

```
LIKE      PAGE    ARTICLE    
id        id      id
userid    name    text
itemid
itemtype
```

and my entities;

Page.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="page")
 */
 protected $likes;
```

Article.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="article")
 */
 protected $likes;
```

Like.php;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="likes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $page;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="likes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $article;
```

My question; How to add WHERE condition?

Like this;

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemid", referencedColumnName="id", condition="itemtype=1")
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible, you will be doing it wrong. It is better to have `article_id` and `page_id` in Like table than yours `item_id` and `itemtype` identifier.

Example:
if you do it as I told above, you will be able to set cascade deletion on DB level `@ORM\JoinColumn(...., onDelete="CASCADE")`. That means that if Article has been deleted, all likes will be automatically deleted too via foreign key.

If you do it your way, then you will have to manually take care of that. Better leave it to database; less code, less chance of an error.

Comment: If I use this way, a field (article_id or page_id) will be empty. Unnecessary field are stacked.

Comment: It is a minor issue, you will be having way more problems if you put identifiers. I use this trick for liking user, image, album, comment, wallpost... No speed difference if it is 500.000 rows or 10.